# Ошибка при компиляции APK с помощью Gradle в Unity

Tags: unity3d, gradle, java

Пытаюсь скомплитить apk через Gradle, но кидает вот такую ошибку. Самое интересное, что вчера делал сборку - проблем не было. Сегодня внезапно такая ошибка появилась[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что там? Не видно.

Comment: CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Final Version\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle' line: 68

Comment: может попробовать юнити запустить с правами администратора